# How to add views inside Listview rows in android

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

How can add add child views inside the listview dynamically.

Any help will be really useful.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: with single value i'm able to create but not sure how to add multiple values .

Comment: when you want to add child views in row?

Comment: right now i'll be getting some values from the server so depending on that i need to add child view inside the listview I know it can be done with expandable listview but not sure how i can add in listview

Comment: Hi Srikanth,
 I have a personal question to you. Tried to get your email id. Please contact me when you see this - nithin9mk@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter for the listview.  In the custom adapter code you inflate your multiple field view.  The adapter then returns this multiple field view as a single row.

This is a good tutorial on it. #3 is about multiple view rows:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to create different ListView rows,but how to create child views inside a particular row based on some values ?

Comment: A multi-level listview tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: no this is not i want :( i need to add child views inside listview rows based on some value which i get from server.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use 2 layout files to accomplish this. One for the structure of the layout itself (i.e. amount of columns you want, etc):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/img1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:text="@string/header" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_line2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3f3f3f">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column_header1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/TextForCol1"
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewForContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And one for the rows:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column_header1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Java class you'll want to do something like this to fill up the ListView:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for (int i=0; i<collectionOfItems.length; i++){

    HashMap<String, String>map=new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("TextForCol1", ValueForCol1AtThisIndex[i]);

    aList.add(map);

    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MyJavaClass.this,
            aList,
            R.layout.the_rows_layout_file_name,
            new String[]{"TextForCol1"},
            new int[]{R.id.column_header1}
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, one in the `onCreate` of your `Activity` class and the next when you have your data available to fill up the `ListView`. Note that you can easily use an `AsyncTask` to fill up the `ListView` in `doInBackground` if you're worried about the slight performance hit of inflating 2 layouts.

Comment: I cant go with this approach because i need to do some operations based on a particular row.

Comment: Then use an `ArrayAdapter` instead of a `SimpleAdapter`.